# how to run a job based on the failure condition of a job in autosys

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

I have two jobs which are Job_A and Job_B.

I want Job_B to run based on the failure condition of Job_A.

Please suggest me how I have to set the JIL for the above condition.

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 1):

In Job_B's definition, include the line:

condition: failure(Job_A)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using the following attribute in JOb_B JIL file (job definition),

```
condition: f(Job_A)
```